# Aggregated double join tSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregate

we have three tables name case, case flow and note. Case to Case flow relation is one to N, and case to note relation is also. The case flow has two fields: start date, end date. And the Note has one date field named created on.
We want to be able to show the notes grouped by case flows (based on comparison of created on and start, end date) and then grouped by cases. Is there a way to build such query by tSQL?

Following APPEAR to be the data as provided from the image (dont do images like that in future please).

```
Case table
CaseID   CaseName
cs1       Test1
cs2       Test2

CaseFlow table
CaseFlowID  CaseID  StartDate  EndDate
cf1         cs1     7/25/2021  7/29/2021
cf2         cs2     7/26/2021  7/27/2021
cf3         cs2     7/27/2021  7/28/2021
cf4         cs2     7/28/2021  7/31/2021

Notes table
NoteID      CaseID    CreatedOn
nt1         cs1       7/25/2021
nt2         cs1       7/27/2021
nt3         cs1       7/27/2021
nt4         cs1       7/30/2021


Expected Result
Case        Flows     Notes
cs1         cf1       nt1
                      nt2
cs2         cf2       null
            cf3       nt3
                      nt4
```

Sample data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1zUT.png)

Comment: **Consumable** sample data, expected results, *your* attempts will all help us help you. What you are asking is completely unclear right now

Comment: @larnu added some sample data

Comment: We need **consumable** sample data. An image doesn't help us help you. And you missed the rest of my comment as well; expected results **and** *your* attempts.

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [sql-server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @larnu I have no idea whether this result could be achieved or not! Just want to know is it possible or not!? If possible? how?

Comment: Without knowing your data, or expected results, we have no way of knowing,@Pey .

Comment: Hi @Pey your expected result is possible to do in any reporting tool. But in query cell value will be repeated.

Comment: @larnu aaah! dont u see the picture? all the data and the results is there

Comment: @RahulBiswas how? is there any walkthrough or article related to this one?

Comment: From my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634453/aggregated-double-join-tsql?noredirect=1#comment121296804_68634453) "An image doesn't help us help you."

Comment: @Larnu ok! bye bye!

Comment: Hi @Pey in your sample output why cf3 show multiple times?

Comment: @RahulBiswas edited the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from how your image showed only 1 record value in the flows column, the returned data will show the repeated value on each row returned.  Your output formatting would be used to remove the duplicate values such as under the case and flows.

Your result overall shows the 4 case flows so you get 4 returned rows.  First I am doing a JOIN to the case table in case you wanted the case name (which I did include in the output).  But going to the notes table, that requires a LEFT JOIN.  Meaning I always want the record from the left side (caseFlow) even if there is no matching record on the right side (notes) for the given case and date created.

One other caveat.  Your case start/end date.  The values you are showing appear to allow for OVERLAP.  Take a look at your case 2 case flow.  You have one from 26-27, then 27-28 and 28-31.  So if you have your transaction on the 27th, there is no definitive way to say it belongs to case flow 2 vs 3 if the date was 27th, or 3 vs 4 if on the 28th... UNLESS the End Date is applied as the note is LESS THAN the end date of the case.  That is why I have the where clause where created on is at or after the start date for the case, but BEFORE the end date.

```
select
      c.caseName,
      cf.caseid,
      cf.caseflowid,
      n.noteid
   from
      CashFlow cf
         JOIN Case c
            on cf.caseid = c.caseid
         LEFT JOIN Notes n
            on cf.caseid = n.caseid
            AND cf.StartDate <= n.CreatedOn
            AND n.CreatedOn < cf.EndDate
```

Comment: @Pey, glad it worked for you, but the more important thing.  Does the explanation provide clarity to you on WHY things work, not just "here's an answer".  Notice too my indentation style of first table, then indent to the JOINING TO table, then telling HOW the relationship between the tables exist.  Helps long-term to know what is related hierarchically.  Check out almost any other SQL-based query I've posted, including many that include self-joins and joining to same table multiple times on different conditions.  Much more readable than blurred together.